Salesforce common framework dependency resolution through devops
As an Azure DevOps engineer, we automate CI/CD to Salesforce org using Salesforce CLI. We have multiple projects (each with single repository) having codebase for different Salesforce projects.
Codebase from different branch is deployed to Salesforce org following branching strategy.
Example:

Project name: myProject
Repository: myProjectRepository
Branches: feature, develop, release and main
Salesforce Org: DEV, SIT, UAT, PROD

There is a plan to create common frameworks (trigger, logger, error-handling, etc.) and push them to new common repository and maintain versioning. Salesforce projects can then use any version of common framework as dependency.
Example:

Project name: myCommonFramework
Repository: myCommonFrameworkRepository
Branches: feature, develop and release

I have checked "packageDirectories" in sfdx-project.json requires the folder to be in --source-dir. I didn't find a way to link required version as "devDependencies" or/and "dependencies" in package.json.
Please could you suggest me any ideas to this solution?

What detailed things are you want to do in Azure DevOps? Can you explain the detailed question/issue you are facing in Azure DevOps?

In Azure DevOps, I need Salesforce core in myProjectRepository to download and deploy common frameworks from myCommonFrameworkRepository. We are also open to use artifact repository if it helps in our solution. My question is - how can we resolve this dependency across external repository?

In Azure DevOps, if you want to download the code files from myCommonFrameworkRepository to myProjectRepository, you can define myCommonFrameworkRepository as a repository resource in the pipeline of myProjectRepository. For more details, see my answer below. @SambitSwain

In Azure DevOps, if you want to download the code files from myCommonFrameworkRepository to myProjectRepository, you can define myCommonFrameworkRepository as a repository resource in the pipeline of myProjectRepository.

If the two repositories are in a same project within the same Azure DevOps organization. In the YAML pipeline of myProjectRepository, you can configure like as blow.
# azure-pipelines.yml

# Set 'myCommonFrameworkRepository' as a repository resource in this pipeline.
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: commonFrameworkRepo  # A customized alias for the repository resource.
    type: git  # Azure Git Repos.
    name: myCommonFrameworkRepository  # The actual name of 'myCommonFrameworkRepository'. 
    ref: main  # The branch checked out by default from 'myCommonFrameworkRepository'.

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
    # Check out files from 'myProjectRepository'.
    - checkout: self
    # Check out files from 'myCommonFrameworkRepository'.
    - checkout: commonFrameworkRepo


If myCommonFrameworkRepository is in a different project (for example, myCommonFramework) within the same Azure DevOps organization. In the YAML pipeline of myProjectRepository, you can configure like as blow.
# azure-pipelines.yml

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: commonFrameworkRepo
    type: git
    name: myCommonFramework/myCommonFrameworkRepository  # projectName/repoName
    ref: main

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - checkout: commonFrameworkRepo


If myCommonFrameworkRepository is in a different Azure DevOps organization. You need to create an Azure Repos service connection in the project of myProjectRepository to connect to myCommonFrameworkRepository.

Then in the YAML pipeline of myProjectRepository, you can configure like as blow.
# azure-pipelines.yml

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: commonFrameworkRepo
    endpoint: myAzGitReposConnection  # Use the Azure Repos service connection.
    type: git
    name: myCommonFramework/myCommonFrameworkRepository  # projectName/repoName
    ref: main

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - checkout: commonFrameworkRepo



For more details, you can reference the following documentations:

Check out multiple repositories in your pipeline
resources.repositories.repository definition
Define a repositories resource



Thank you for your help, I will test the changes are let you know.

@SambitSwain, Have you tried the repositories resource in your YAML pipeline as suggested in my above answer? Does it work for you?

I have done my implementation as you suggested, and now I am waiting for IT approval to read resource from external ADO. We expect to have an outcome by this week.

@SambitSwain, Okay. Go ahead please.
